# render call in hook_node_presave uses admin theme

Tags: theming, hooks

I am using `hook_node_presave()` to render my node and then save the output to a field `field_node_cache`.  However, when I do this, the renderer uses the admin theme, whereas I would like to use the site's main theme.

Is there a way to force it to use the site's main theme without disabling the admin theme?

```
function MYMODULE_node_presave(NodeInterface $entity) {
  switch ($entity->getType()) {
    case 'MY_CONTENT_TYPE':
      $render_controller = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder($entity->getEntityTypeId());
      $render_output = $render_controller->view($entity, 'MY_VIEW_MODE', 'ja');
      $html = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderPlain($render_output);

      $entity->set('field_text_main_display', $html);
      $entity->field_node_cache->format = 'MY_FORMAT';
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to work around this is to go to `/admin/appearance` and uncheck `Use the administration theme when editing or creating content`.

Alternately, you can create a separate user account that does not have permission **View the administration theme** and use that account to create content.